# Does Write-Ahead-Logging allow me to make concurrent changes to a table?

Tags: sqlite, concurrency, write-ahead-logging

In Sqlite3, Write-Ahead-Logging mode allows one process to read a table, while another is writing to it. It doesn't say anything about one process writing and another deleting/updating.

Is this possible in Sqlite3?

Comment: Are you asking about 2 or more processes changing data in the same table, at the same time?

Comment: Yes it may occur at the same time. But, It probably cannot be achieved as the sqlite3 docs says. The one way is handle the lock state and trying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DELETE` and/or an `UPDATE` are both writes!

Only one process can write at any one time - that is an `INSERT`, an `UPDATE` or a `DELETE` at the same time. You can `SELECT` with as many processes as you like, but only one of the others at a time!